# How to get the serial number of the hard drive on which I am working?

Tags: hard-drive, wmic, serial-number

For get the serial number of all hard drives in my computer, I use:

```
wmic diskdrive get serialnumber
```

But, I want to get the serial number of the hard drive where I am working.

I explain:
I have 2 hard drives, one of them has 2 partitions C and D. The other has one partition E. With the command line, if I am working in C partition, when I type the `wmic` command, I want to get only the serial number of the hard drive which has this partition, not the serial of the hard drive with the E partition.

I want to make a license code for my software. you can install the software in any partition. i want the serial number of the hard drive that contains these partition specifycally. the volume serial number of the partition changes when you format, reinstall, etc, but the serial number of the hard drive not. i know there are softwares to change the serial number, but my possible clients are not so smarts.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This question is about how to get the serial number of a specific drive. Answers in the alleged duplicate will provide a list of all drives and their serial numbers but no way to match those serial numbers to a specific hard disk or Windows drive letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your replies. I found an answer that is what I need, here I share it with you. The command is in powershell:

```
Get-Disk (Get-Partition -DriveLetter 'C').DiskNumber
```

The output is something like this:

```
Number Friendly Name Serial Number  HealthStatus OperationalStatus       Total Size Partition Style
------ ------------- -------------------------------------------------- 
0      ST3802110AS    5LR2DQ65       Healthy          Online               74.53 GB    MBR
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Powershell script I made that hopefully does what you want.

1. Open Powershell
2. Copy and paste this:

> ```
> $volumes = get-wmiobject Win32_Volume
> foreach ($vol in $volumes) 
>   {
>     if($vol.Caption -eq 'c:\')
>       {
>         $vol | fl Caption,Name,DeviceID,SerialNumber 
>       }
>   }
> pause
> ```

This should get you what you want in relation to the C:\ drive. If you want a different drive letter, simply change it in the script above on the 4th line where it says `c:\`

The **output** will look like:

```
Caption      : C:\
Name         : C:\
DeviceID     : \\?\Volume{770f1368-bacc-4401-98db-a6c43bc4ef11}\
SerialNumber : 3469401274
```

**Note**: If you want all the available drive info and not just those 4 things, you can remove `| fl Caption,Name,DeviceID,SerialNumber` from the above and just leave `$vol` on that line instead.

Comment: That answer does not help me because that script returns a serial that differs from the hard drive serial. Another way to focus my question is which partitions belong to a specific disk. There is a command `wmic diskdrive get partitions`, that returns the number of partitions of all hard drives. If there was a command that allows me to obtain the names of the partitions (C, D, etc) of each disk, it would be great

Comment: You should know that there is no guaranteed way to get ANY hardware serial numbers on modern PCs. Back in the day Intel Pentium II processors had BIOS options to enable CPU serial numbers, however nefarious folks would use this to track you, Intel completely disabled it, as well as MANY other HW manufacturers. In fact, I have an new Samsung NVMe drive which always returns all zeros for it's serial number.

Comment: Also just a thought, but, maybe hash against the CPUID instead for your license key?

Comment: @DarilAlemán [Find partition letters on physical drives using wmic](//superuser.com/q/634842)